# Resource linking fails on lStar

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a React Native application. My Android builds began to fail in the [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) environment (and locally) without any changes.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopmentDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDevelopmentDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2682: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

According to *[Android: Resource linking fails on test execution even when nothing has been changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019631/android-resource-linking-fails-on-test-execution-even-when-nothing-has-been-cha)*, this happened because some library got upgraded.

**lStar** needs **compileSdkVersion 31** and my project used **compileSdkVersion 28**.

How can I track which libraries got updated recently, or which library is causing this?

Comment: Same happened to me.
error shows as `core-1.7.0-alpha02\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.`

Comment: Same just started happening for me about 30 minutes ago too. I'm so confused since the build went out fine this morning

Comment: Same for me. Started happening about 90 mins ago with no code changes.

Comment: *lStar needs compileSdkVersion 31 and my project used compileSdkVersion 28.*
as a temporary fix I've update the compileSdkVersion to 31

Comment: For my project, compileSdkVersion 31 will break other things.

Comment: Same for me, I use flutter on my project.

Comment: A similar problem happened to my flutter yesterday

Comment: Referenced at Reddit: *[Android builds fail due to core-1.7.0-alpha02 release](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/ph2596/android_builds_fail_due_to_core170alpha02_release/)*

Comment: Another question: *[Message "error: resource android:attr/lStar not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033022/error-resource-androidattr-lstar-not-found)*

Comment: What is *"lStar"*?

Comment: It is coming in androidx.core:core:1.7.0->values.xml. Log says to increase the minSdkVersion to 24 or above.

Comment: ... and change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 OS version. And errors in mine went away.

Comment: lStar is described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Comment: For those using react native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74341327/4792461

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to your *package.json* file and delete as many dependencies as you can until the project builds successfully. Then start adding back the dependencies one by one to detect which ones have troubles.

Then you can manually patch those dependencies by acceding them on node_modules/[dependencie]/android/build.gradle and setting **androidx.core:core-ktx:** or **androidx.core:core:** to a specific version (1.6.0 in my case).

Comment: What was the dependency in your case?

Comment: You can open the `node_modules` folder using **vscode** and search(Ctrl+Shift+F) for **androidx.core:core** and **androidx.core:core-ktx**

Comment: @martin, thank you so much! The issue was androidx.core:core version on netinfo's build.gradle.

Comment: @radosław-rudnicki latest version is fine (5.9.7) but go into 'node_modules\@react-native-community\netinfo\android\build.gradle' and change line 67 from implementation "androidx.core:core:$androidXCore" to implementation "androidx.core:core:1.6.0"

Comment: @RadosławRudnicki I changed **implementation "androidx.core:core:$androidXCore"** on netinfo's **build.gradle** to version **1.0.1**. Then I'll create a patch with **patch-package**

Comment: when I have modified the file **node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android/build.gradle** replacing line number 67
    `implementation "androidx.core:core:$androidXCore"`
to 
    `implementation "androidx.core:core:1.6.0"`
gradlew succeeded

Thanks guys

Comment: i am not able to solve the issue , above mentioned technique doesnot work .

Comment: Replace implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+" with 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' in your project or module level gradle will fix  the issue. There is no need to increase the compileSdkVersion.

Comment: check my answer for a more detailed way on how to find which dependency to remove

Comment: Thanks so much! Mine was also @react-native-communtiy/netinfo. I just had to upgrade it to ^6.0.1

Comment: upgrading @react-native-community\netinfo from 5.9.7 to 6.0.1 did the job for me - all builds fine

Comment: Generally speaking, it's also a good idea to specify the exact version for each dependency (and in some cases sub-dependencies) in `package.json` to avoid changes from one build to another.

Answer (score 65):

The *problem* is `@react-native-community/netinfo`. Just try to update the package using

```
yarn add @react-native-community/netinfo
```

or

```
npm update @react-native-community/netinfo
```

There isn't any need to change anything over your Gradle or Android files as those might mess things up even more.

Comment: Yep, this one worked for us too. Upgraded from 5.x.x to 6.0.1 and no regression issues spotted so far 

Comment: This solved my problem but why did it break in the first place? My `@react-native-community/netinfo` was set to `5.9.0` for some time and it worked like a charm... really annoying.

Comment: Wow this is really bad form.  Nothing changed on my end and then it stops working one day!!!  This fixed my problem.

Comment: @Elias because of [this](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/commit/d40d9b5704a7d6573f3832586626aceac8b680bd), which was fixed in the commit i've linked to, the "actual issue" is that this library was using the + shortcut which is to say "get the latest", a new, breaking, version of the androidXCore, was released upstream which this library was set to automatically use, but either the library or your app was not prepared for it so when you built it all fell apart.

Comment: Many thanks really ...
This wasn't an obvious problem to solve !

Comment: In my case, I already have version 6.0.x and this didn't fix it. I'll try the android native solutions

Answer (score 33):

Go to *android/build.gradle* and add **androidXCore = "1.6.0"** to **ext**:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"
}
```

Comment: Is this not just a variable?  Some of the libraries must have to use it as a version? Or it is predefined to be used as such?

Comment: It is coming in androidx.core:core:1.7.0->values.xml. Log says to increase the minSdkVersion to 24 or above.

Comment: It went away when changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 OS version.

Comment: Merely adding a variable did not work, hence your solution also did not work. So please elaborate where this variable is used (in which dependency version).

Answer (score 29):

#### Native Android:

The issue occurs because of **androidx.core:core-ktx**.

If you are using *core-ktx*, change

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

if you are not using core-ktx maybe one of your dependent libraries is using *androidx.core:core-ktx*.

**Solution 1:** Figure out the library using **core-ktx** and try not to use it.

*Or*:

**Solution 2:** Update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`  to `31`

*Or*:

**Solution 3:** In app:build.grandle add below code: *hou andy's solution*

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine. also my latest android studio 4.1 layout preview was not showing and after using this code all my layout got shown. Thanks

Comment: Solution 2 worked!!!!

Answer (score 23):

It looks like there is a bug with the alpha02 version of *core-ktx*.

There might be two reasons that this is happening to you project if you didn't upgrade it recently:

1. You are using

   `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"`

   In this case, replace it with

   `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"` (or whichever version works for you)
2. Some library is using that alpha02 version

   **In this case you have two options:**

   1. temporarily increase to compileSdkVersion 31
   2. Remove or downgrade the dependency that is using alpha02

   Run

   ```
    ./gradlew :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
   ```

   A text file with dependency tree will be added to your project.

   Open the file and you will see something like this

   ```
    +--- MyApp:mylibrary:unspecified
    |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
    |         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
    |         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
    |         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
    |         |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
         |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-25.3.1.jar
   ```

   Search for something similar to this

   ```
    androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0 -> 1.7.0-alpha-02
   ```

   Track down which dependency is using that. To fix it you might need to either remove the dependency or downgrade it to an older version.

Comment: It is coming in androidx.core:core:1.7.0->values.xml. Log says to increase the minSdkVersion to 24 or above.
It went away when changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 OS version.

Answer (score 14):

I changed version 29 to 31 in compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion of the *build.gradle* file in the *android* folder. It solved my problem.

Comment: Yes; the same worked for me too. My changes `buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"`, `compileSdkVersion = 31` and `targetSdkVersion = 31`

Comment: I referred to the AndroidManifest.xml of the package whose file contains the error point - and found that the targetSdkVersion was higher than what I had for the project. So increased it my project's gradle file - and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

Force use this androidx-core version in your app module file *build.gradle*:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

It's seems to work for me!

Comment: This helped me in a bundle with bumping androidx.core:core-ktx to 1.6.0. Thanks man!

Comment: The only thing that helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

**Solution for Flutter:**

Simply search globally for `core-ktx` dependencies for all the Flutter packages including the Flutter project *android* folder and set the `1.6.0` version instead of `+`.

**From:**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

**To:**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

I faced the same issue with the `audioplayers` Flutter package in older version.

Comment: Have a look at audioplayers v0.19.1, as it solves this issue (https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/changelog)

Comment: @Manu Thanks, I already review the same after the solution and upgrade the packages. But this answer might help for those who might want to use an older version or facing issues with other packages.

Answer (score 13):

Changing android/build.gradle and adding androidXCore = "1.6.0" worked for me.

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"    //Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**For Unity Game Engine Builds**

In case someone ends up here searching for a solution with their Unity builds, the solution is to add

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
    force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
  }
}
```

At the end of your *launcherTemplate.gradle* file in *Plugins/Android*.

Comment: What is a *"Unity build"*? The word "Unity" is heavily overloaded. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69045181/edit) some reference to (authoritative) documentation? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: It worked for me after I added `force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'` to my AndroidManifest.xml (I had this error with a normal Android project)

Answer (score 12):

If you're using React Native and coming here after November 4, 2022, this may be the solution: [github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) React Native team messed something up with version and thats the reason why we have this message..

Comment: No way that this did the trick :)

Comment: Could you link the comment from this issue that actually solves this problem, or tell us the solution? The issue has 360+ comments and it's hard to understand what to actually do.

Comment: @reesaspieces You may follow the first post of React team: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#issue-1436785719 and patch your react-native with corresponding version.

Answer (score 8):

### Solution for Cordova

For those who have this issue in a `Cordova` application context like me and using an Android API version older than `31` (`29` in my case), I found a clean way to **bypass it**.

#### TL;DR

If you are using the plugin `cordova.plugins.diagnostic`, **uninstall it** first then **reinstall it** using the following **argument**:

```sh
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --variable ANDROIDX_VERSION=1.0.0
```

Refresh the whole android platform and you're project should not be using the `androidx.core:core:1.7.0-beta02` anymore.

---

#### Full explaination

Solutions already mentionned in the thread (gradle rules to force a certain version of a package) will not work with `Cordova` as it handles the whole gradle process on it's own (gathering plugins dependencies, config.xml settings and processing everything) and it's really difficult to override specific things.
I did not manage to fix our problem using `resolutionStrategy` for example.

And migrating to `Android API 31` isn't always an easy solution (plugins & dependencies need to support it in particular)

Instead, I tried to find which of my installed plugins were having a dependency linked to the `androidx.core:core` package, which breaks everything in its `1.7.0-beta02` version.

No one in my list was directly using it, but I found (with the help of the builded `build.gradle`) that the following package `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` was used and since it's related to `AndroidX` as well, I digged a bit and I quickly found-out that the version used for it was `1.+` (**latest 1.xx**).

Checking on mavenrepo, `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` has our buggy package `androidx.core:core` as dependency (`1.7.0-beta02` on the latest).

After a quick search with my IDE, I found the definition of the dependency :

```xml
<framework src="androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$ANDROIDX_VERSION" />
```

It was used **by a plugin** named `cordova-diagnostic-plugin`. (Pretty common in a `Cordova` project, it basically handles Android settings, permissions and hardware stuff)

I noticed that an **environment variable** was used to define the package version (and set by default to `1.+`).
Going on the plugin's GitHub documentation : https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#androidx-library will tell you that you can indeed set a custom version when installing the plugin with the Cordova command.

Which I did (I removed the plugin first):

```sh
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --variable ANDROIDX_VERSION=1.0.0
```

After rebuilding the android platform, I started a new build and it was finally successful !

`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0` was used as well as the `androidx.core:core` package in its `1.0.0` version. No more `error: resource android attr/lStar not found` issue !

To sum-up : check your **plugins dependencies** and if possible, **set static versions** instead of "latest". In that way, you can (in most cases) avoid using **alpha/beta releases**, which could be instable or not supporting your current environment.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I had same issue in my ionic cordova app and disgnostic plugin was there. Followed above steps and boom, error went away :)

Comment: Thanks for this! Tried this with AndroidX 1.6.0, and that works too. The issue seems to be only in the 1.7.0-beta02.

Comment: Thank you very much for your research!

Comment: Thank you, good sir. To expand your answer: this error is introduced by 1.4.0, switching to **androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0** solves the build problem perfectly!

Answer (score 8):

Changing appcompat version to 1.3.0 worked for me

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved it for me. Actually, I want to use latest version (1.4.0), but Android Studio giving the error without any suggestions really sucks.

Comment: I downgrade 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0' to 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'. this worked for me.

Comment: in which file is that ?

Comment: @PrinceHamza in app level build.gradle file

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was with `react-native-screen-brightness`, so I just changed `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1+'` to `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'` in file *android/build.gradle*.

Answer (score 6):

Update your gradel.build

```
compileSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Comment: For me I had to force the SDK version on subproject dependencies: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298232/6877668

Answer (score 5):

In my case problem was with *@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.3.3*, so I just removed the netinfo library and installed it again with the latest version and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding `androidXCore = "1.6.0"` solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

## If you getting this issue in Android

**if you using**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

**just replace it with:**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

and in gradle-wrapper.properties: distributionUrl is:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

## ________________________________________________________________

## Other wise

and if you want to use

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

just change **distributionUrl** in gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by replacing

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
```

with this one:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
```

If you have for some reason both, set only the *ktx* version.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't figure out which library was causing the problem and upgrading compileSDK version was breaking the app, but I went to the [core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) and you can see that the core library got updated a day back. So the alpha-02 was causing the problem.

I fixed my problem by converting

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

to

```
 implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

in the build Gradle file (app level) and then **Sync now**.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the answer native android is correct:

"It looks like there is a bug with the alpha02 version of core-ktx"

You are using

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

In this case, replace it with

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

but in many cases, it doesn't help because when you don't use explicit this dependency. What happened is jetbrain convert old library automatically to use androidx latest library, that's the origin of the issue. so you need to check every dependency implement in your build.gradle and update it to androidx version. for me it's a old project, the room before is:

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:+"   
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:+"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

and you need add this in your build.gradle (you can add it globally in the end of the file):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the same error

Solved the issue in may case by

changing

> implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
> to

> **implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"**(updated)

issue fixed... thanks to above solution

Answer (score 2):

While many of the solutions indicate to use

`androidx.core:core:1.6.0`

I discovered that in my project, one module was using version 1.7.0

After changing it to 1.6.0, this problem went away. So if you have multiple modules, make sure you check all of the build.gradle files that they are all using the same version.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else found this page having issues with react-native, there is information and a hot-fix available here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210.

> [READ ME] [FIX INSIDE] Android build failures happening since Nov 4th 2022 #35210

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 2022

##### Solution

When this problem arises, it's likely one of your dependencies set **compileSdkVersion** to **30 or less** in it's `build.gradle` file. You have to find that package and find a way to set the **compileSdkVersion** to **31**.

##### My Solution

I faced this problem in React Native and it turned out one of my dependencies, namely **[react-native-device-number](https://github.com/mdrajibsk8/react-native-device-number)** basically set **compileSdkVersion** to **29** in it's `build.gradle`. I had to change it to **31** and the problem was solved.

For me I didn't deem it good to edit the package's codes locally as it can cause issues when updating it, and editing the code won't solve the problem when run on CI/CD environments. So I had to fork the package on Github, make the changes, then install the forked version in my React Native project.

Here's the signature for installing node.js package from Github

```bash
npm install github_username/repo_name/#branch_name
```

And here's the entry in my package.json after the installation
`package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "react-native-device-number": "github:stanleyugwu/react-native-device-number#develop"
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had the same issue in React Native 0.69.7 with this library: TronNatthakorn/react-native-wheel-pick. Your solution worked for me. Did a PR to that repo with this fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the working solution was updating `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 31 in the app-level Gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using compileSdkVersion lower than 31, use 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me.

I removed the Huawei IAP libraries, but I forgot to delete the `agconnect-services.json` file provided by Huawei. So after deleting that file, all went well.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing implementation "**androidx.core:core-ktx:+**" with 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' in your project or module level Gradle file will fix the issue. There isn't any need to increase the compileSdkVersion.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update Gradle
2. Update the SDK to version 31
3. Accept the license
4. Set compileSdkVersion to 31 in the build Gradle file
5. Sync

Ready to go!

Comment: Just adding a note, I had to force SDK version on all subprojectsin order to fix this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298232/6877668

Answer (score 1):

Find all dependencies in your project:

Replace all: implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
with the specified version: 1.6.0, because with the `+`, you always use the newest version.

Now *androidx.core:core-ktx* updates to the *1.7.0-alpha* version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case updating `@react-native-community/netinfo` to `6.0.2` plus adding `coreVersion = "1.6.0"` into `build.gradle` for package `@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication` which is searching for this variable resolved the issue.

Comment: Hello lukhol what is the 'exact code to add 1.6.0 into build.gradle for package @invertase/react-native-apple-auhentication?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by updating the @react-native-community/netinfo library.

> npm update @react-native-community/netinfo

Answer (score 1):

## core-1.7.0-alpha02

**Suddenly build is failing without any code change?**

It is quite common. This happened with me many times and most recently it happened with core-1.7.0-alpha02. My project was building fine and one day it stooped.

### What might be the issue?

> Gradle sync

Sometimes new version of libraries break project.

### Solution?

Force you gradle to use the **old stable** versions. In this case `androidx.core:core:1.6.0` was the stable release. You can see always find the stable version information

[image]

### How to use older version of library?

Go to gradle.build (app level) and paste this

```
//Forcing 1.6.0 instead of 1.7.0-alpha02
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
       force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'    //This is stable version right now.
   }
}
```

## Bonus:

General rule to fix these issues?

- Look for the library that causing issue.
- Find the stable version on [Google Android Developer's Page](https://developer.android.com/)
- Force your Gradle to use the stable
  version.

In my case this was the error message

```
/Users/singhr1/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1ae857b36375746f9b0fa09af0c656f3/core-1.7.0-beta02/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

So the culprit was `core-1.7.0-beta02`.
I found the stable version on Developer's page and forced my Gradle to use it.

Answer (score 1):

FOR IONIC CORDOVA, in the build.gradle where all your dependencies are put this

build.gradle

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    androidXCore = "1.6.0".  <---------- this is important
}
```

configurations.all{

```
resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' <---------- this is important
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'  <-----this is important
    }
```

}

dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"  <-----this is important
implementation "androidx.core:core:1.6.0" <-----this is important
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using ionic 3 and firebase, the solution is change the project.properties and replace some androidx.core lines:

**Before**

```
# Project target.
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-support-google-services/nosveja-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/nosveja-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.+
cordova.system.library.9=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
cordova.system.library.11=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
cordova.system.library.12=androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.+
cordova.system.library.13=androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+
```

**After**

```
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-support-google-services/nosveja-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/nosveja-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.+
cordova.system.library.9=androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing `compileSdkVersion = 29` and `targetSdkVersion = 29` to `compileSdkVersion = 31` and `targetSdkVersion = 31` works without changing `androidxCoreVersion =  '1.2.0'` to `androidxCoreVersion =  '1.6.0'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by newer version of `androidx.core:core-ktx` missing `lStar`.

To find the package causing the problem, I searched through all installed node_modules for `core-ktx:` and found `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"` in the `react-native-camera-kit` package.

I would like to lock this to `core-ktx:1.6.0` to fix the build issue. Using
[patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) that is straight forward (make sure you have a fresh package installation without build artifacts):

- Change `core-ktx:+` to `core-ktx:1.6.0` in the `build.gradle` file, in my case `node_modules/react-native-camera-kit/android/build.gradle`
- Run `yarn patch-package <package to fix>`, in my case `yarn patch-package react-native-camera-kit`
- Rebuild for Android to check that it works
- Commit patch

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by the line in build.grale, `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"`.

After I added a new empty activity to the project with Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4, Android Studio altered the build.gradle file

from:
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"`

to:
`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding kotlin-gradle-plugin in `build.gradle` fixed the issue for me: `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"`