# Android resource linking failed at values.xml 105

Tags: android, android-studio

The code was running successfully before, suddenly this error started appearing whenever I try to build the app.

The error is in value.xml at line 150 which is non editable

````
        <!-- Base color for this state. -->
        <attr name="android:color"/>
        <!-- Alpha multiplier applied to the base color. -->
        <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
        <attr name="android:alpha"/>
        <!-- Perceptual luminance applied to the base color. From 0 to 100. -->
        <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
        <attr name="android:lStar"/>
    </declare-styleable> ```
````

Comment: So what's the complete error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Build Error: "lStar not found..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041630/android-build-error-lstar-not-found)