# Run app use Kotlin build failed AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: kotlin

I am coding android app by Kotlin. When run app is error build failed C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\06149af1d4a4f067b7c8778b7e903c47\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
How to fix this error ?? Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message "error: resource android:attr/lStar not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033022/message-error-resource-androidattr-lstar-not-found)

Comment: No, i use kotlin and when build project is above error

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error. The recycler view library I added was 1.3.0- alpha-1. When I changed it to the previous stable version, i.e., 1.2.1, then the error was resolved. Maybe you can also try to change the versions of the imported libraries to their stable versions.