# How solve the error in android studio: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio

../../AndroidStudioProjects/xxxxx/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/85d86ad1681edc5ad46b44e92265cc70/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml

C:\Users\srini\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxxx\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\85d86ad1681edc5ad46b44e92265cc70\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033022/message-error-resource-androidattr-lstar-not-found

Comment: Hey man, how are you? I understand what you are trying to ask, however, the question itself is unclear in a few ways, for example you haven't specified what you are using, nor included any code. I also advise you to explain what you are trying to do and SPECIALLY what you have tried to fix the error you are getting. Best of luck and happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

The rebuild mentioned above may help, but I've had issues with gradle that persist.

Here is a good resource.

https://makmodo.com/android-resource-linking-failed/

But, in short, you may want to go through and open every XML file without scanning or running it. This will cause android to pinpoint any error occuring and you can at least start to narrow down where the error is coming from.

Then, you'll want to run a stacktrace, `gradlew build --stacktrace`

Another option, depending on when you run into the error is to start slowly backing up. Undo your last change, build, run ,etc.. and then get it to a point where it is running. This seems obvious, but often times it is the simple things that are overlooked.