# I got the error when i run the flutter app

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

```
Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\Lunix\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0ce731f8c62e88af9af421907435d7da\transformed\core-1.8.0\res\values\values.xml:104:5-113:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050529/14957991 ?

Comment: that was about the react native and not run in flutter app