# flutter AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to build the apk of my project but I got:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\pc\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1c118aff0ddf4faaf93ec03867fed550\transformed\core-1.9.0-rc01\res\values\values.xml:104:5-113:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

I don't know what this means, nor how to solve it, I saw online that I should have this line

```
  implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

in mine app/build.grande but I tried and nothing changes.

Plugins I'm currently using:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.0.0
  telephony: ^0.2.0
  audioplayers: any
  flutter_audio_recorder2: ^0.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
  image_picker: any
  imgur: any
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  flutter_sms: ^2.3.3
  audio_session: ^0.1.10
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
  flutter_sound_platform_interface: ^9.2.13
  lottie: ^1.4.1
  file_picker: ^5.0.1
  environment: ^0.0.2
  argon_buttons_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.7
  background_sms: ^0.0.4
  animations: ^2.0.3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69033022/10157127 may help

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I saw that question but in my case I'm not using Cordova plugin

Comment: I just added the list of plugins I'm using for my project.

Comment: try `audioplayers: ^1.0.1`

Comment: I tried but I can't (or at least I think) because I get this other error: Because every version of imgur depends on http ^0.12.0+2 and audioplayers >=0.19.0 depends on http ^0.13.1, imgur is incompatible with audioplayers >=0.19.0.
So, because sms_camera depends on both audioplayers ^1.0.1 and imgur any, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because sms_camera depends on both audioplayers ^1.0.1 and imgur any, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Comment: how about using `imgur:any` with `audioplayers: ^1.0.1`

Comment: That's the case XD, I already set imgur to any

Comment: sorry, I didnt notice, try to use update version for all package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the http package to the latest one by including `dependency_overrides` in the `pubspec.yaml`. It's going to be like the following:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  http:
    version: ">=0.13.5"
```

Also, set `audioplayers` version to `^1.0.1`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^1.0.1
  # ...
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was struggling this issue for days