# My React Native app is not working ,getting Failed on executing 77% - (Task :react-native-payments:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED)

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on app , it is opening before a few days ago but now it is getting failed on executing after 72% and showing below error.

------------------ Error -----------------------

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-payments:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Task :react-native-payments:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

[image: Screenshot of Error - 1]

[image: Screenshot of Error - 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when some plugin has old android support dependencies instead of using the new AndroidX equivalent.
To fix this issue, [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) by the help of [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) by running following command

```
npx jetify
```

from root of your project folder before taking build.

Comment: Thanks, It works now but failed after 92%.

Error :
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\saqib\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7935daf201f6df74966f001430bb7ed9\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050529/10657559