flutter ext.kotlin_version dont build apk
I have old project need updates, after updating codes as   sdk: ^3.5.0
I had ext.kotlin_version problem, the problems starts that all Gradle in new structures so I can't solve it with search's result
here the log when "flutter build apk"
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7428d87eca04b8a66b03c2875f74aed6/transformed/fragment-1.7.1-api.jar!/META-INF/fragment_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3e80ee7d0bbfaf800710e08738ee8d47/transformed/jetified-activity-1.8.1-api.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e5a134e3998c339ac98114dba08f806b/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cc2e34c1141d5416fc8834f9fbd0b13b/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6efc486cc614b1c134085cbfe0dc1ea1/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/66a15401fa95fa1def8bcb39dad50d48/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7cb5459602d20c6c9df4ece3d17e4097/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-process-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-process_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.7.0/85334205d65cca70ed0109c3acbd29e22a2d9cb1/lifecycle-common-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/818745901e6e8b25a6c3ef15130c84d6/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/310070c73b9e3fa50e93681b69530d3f/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8f74a46915e4902e43fc2ba4d5115365/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.13.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a174211aaae51cc22f97d3830203be9a/transformed/core-1.13.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ab76a8d862156f391d4c9c67a7f8d883/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1-api.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7bf56b97a18154574b7fd11eb5e856ee/transformed/jetified-window-1.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/window_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ea71884a7a9f9ec5614eb47fe12fe2b6/transformed/jetified-window-java-1.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/window-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f66114939cca7f864f09af78b910bb1f/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/442fc1ee1afc19819871375e623c976a/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8020430956ebf7f2e70e0169ef7f1774/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8020430956ebf7f2e70e0169ef7f1774/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8020430956ebf7f2e70e0169ef7f1774/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Husamuldeen/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ac89cfd23cf522f48151b0c70f16f4ac/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 2776 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatruqchi\key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           94.0s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                 │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of            │
│ E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy\android\settings.gradle.                                           │
│                                                                                                        │
│ Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update                                │
│ E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy\android\build.gradle                                               │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy> 
PS E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy>
PS E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy>
PS E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy>
PS E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy> flutter build apk

Note: C:\Users\Husamuldeen\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_beep-1.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\gonoter\flutter_beep\FlutterBeepPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 2776 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatruqchi\key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           46.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1


it's some thing that i never deal with before
please help
thank you
update the log...
after taking "Soumyajit Das" & "Al-Hashimy" solution the main issue still the same (kotlin version problem) but the log changed

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_beep:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy\build\flutter_beep\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_barcode_scanner:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:E:\AndroidStudioProjects\alatraqchy\build\flutter_barcode_scanner\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:6135: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           69.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1


The error coming from the keystore file what you've mentioned in your

android/app/build.gradle file
 signingConfigs {
 release {
     keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
     keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
     storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
     storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
 }



Please give a correct path of that jks file, it will build the apk successfully

I did it as your advice but the main issue is the same (kotlin version problem) i updated the log in the post, please take a look at it, thank you

Please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033022/message-error-resource-androidattr-lstar-not-found

that's didn't solve the problem, i think it's the used packages don't match with the kotlin version, and i can't delete the packages because i need it

Ok I have to look at the code to solve the error

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

try in build gradle
allprojects {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'\\ add this line
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

