# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found. [React-Native]

Tags: android, react-native

I am unaware on how to fix this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/merbaz/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/31e0fc2a502730d221428a92e4aa0ec1/core-1.7.0-alpha02/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

I have tried `./gradlew clean` but of no use.

Here is the complete log of the build error

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_analytics
:react-native-firebase_analytics package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_analytics:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_analytics package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics/package.json
:react-native-firebase_analytics:version set from package.json: 11.5.0 (11,5,0 - 11005000)
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.minSdk using custom value: 23
:react-native-firebase_analytics:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 18.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 8.4.6 (8,4,6 - 8004006)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 23
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_crashlytics
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics/package.json
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:version set from package.json: 8.4.11 (8,4,11 - 8004011)
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.minSdk using custom value: 23
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_dynamic-links
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links/package.json
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:version set from package.json: 10.5.1 (10,5,1 - 10005001)
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:android.minSdk using custom value: 23
:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_messaging
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:firebase.bom using default value: 25.12.0
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:version set from package.json: 11.2.0 (11,2,0 - 11002000)
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.minSdk using custom value: 23
:react-native-firebase_messaging:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v11.5.0 but found v8.4.6, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.5.0 but found v8.4.6, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v11.2.0 but found v8.4.6, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
537 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 535 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/merbaz/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/31e0fc2a502730d221428a92e4aa0ec1/core-1.7.0-alpha02/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 19s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/merbaz/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/31e0fc2a502730d221428a92e4aa0ec1/core-1.7.0-alpha02/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
         

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 19s

    at makeError (/Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/merbaz/ilmofy-mobile-apps/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

Comment: try cd android && ./gradlew cleean and then cd .. and run again

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar/69024140#69024140

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource linking fails on lStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).