# Android Studio Error :114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, chaquopy

[Here is the error that I am facing while using chaquopy with android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHDIz.png)

Whenever I try to build apk, then it opens values.xml and points to a line

Error is on line 105 :

```
<declare-styleable name="ColorStateListItem">
    <!-- Base color for this state. -->
    <attr name="android:color"/>
    <!-- Alpha multiplier applied to the base color. -->
    <attr format="float" name="alpha"/>
    <attr name="android:alpha"/>
    <!-- Perceptual luminance applied to the base color. From 0 to 100. -->
    <attr format="float" name="lStar"/>
    <attr name="android:lStar"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I am not able to post full values.xml file because of words limit. comment down if you need full file.

Please help me out.

Comment: I think the message indicates that the error is between lines 105 and 114. Can you edit your question to include those 10 lines?

Comment: Ok thx for your response
I added those 10 lines.
You may check it
And please give me any solution for this

Comment: I faced this problem before when try to set `sdkversion:31`. The reason is about dependencies version(`android.test.ext`? I don't remember exactly). I recommand you try version change of dependencies in build.gradle .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message "error: resource android:attr/lStar not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033022/message-error-resource-androidattr-lstar-not-found)

Comment: Or this: [Resource linking fails on lStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar)

Comment: Thx mhsmith ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021225/resource-linking-fails-on-lstar
This may help me but the issue is I am using chaquopy which uses SDK version 30 and according to this post shared by you, Istar needs SDK version 31. So please tell me how can I download chaquopy SDK for version31

Comment: Thx to you also live anyway, let me try your suggestion then I will inform you it worked or not

Comment: Chaquopy does not require SDK version 30. The current version (Chaquopy 10.0.1) supports any SDK version between 16 and 31.

Answer (score 2):

uninstall your old version of android studio

install the latest version from android studio site

https://developer.android.com/studio

it worked for me :-)